# Unit testing a Django BoundField

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-forms

I have a form that a user submits that has a lot of processing on the back end. In that processing, I create a dictionary:

```
def function_that_returns_form_data(form, ...):
    form_data = {'account' : form['account'], ...}
    return form_data
```

My unit test testing the function which returns the dictionary looks something like:

```
self.form = PaymentForm(data=...)
returned_dict = function_that_returns_form_data(self.form, ...)
expected_dict = {'account' : self.form['account'], ...}

self.assertEqual(expected_dict, function_returning_form_data)
```

All the items in `returned_dict` and `expected_dict` match except for 'account', which causes an error:

`AssertionError: Lists differ: ... First differing element 0: 
{'account': <django.forms.forms.BoundField object at 0x043E6F50>, ...
{'account': <django.forms.forms.BoundField object at 0x043E64B0>, ...`

I'm POSITIVE that these objects are the same, and I want to pass along the object instead of pulling out all of its fields individually. How can I get Django to test a bound field with a normal comparison (of the field's value) instead of comparing the location of the object in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Asking for `self.form` gives me gibberish, but `self.form__dict__['data']['field_i_want']` works.

I don't know why I need to access fields in a bound form in such a long-winded way.